# Ellipsis plotting in Dart

Tags: dart, math, matrix, geometry

I want to create an ellipsis plotter for Minecraft players that I know. I have a Dart class:

```dart
class Ellipse with EquatableMixin implements Comparable<Ellipse> {
  const Ellipse(this.width, this.depth) : assert((width > 0) && (depth > 0));

  final int width;
  final int depth;

  @override
  int compareTo(Ellipse other) {
    final widthResult = width.compareTo(other.width);
    if (widthResult != 0) return widthResult;
    return depth.compareTo(other.depth);
  }

  List<List<bool>> get blocks {
    final blocks = List.generate(depth, (_) => List.filled(width, false));

    final a = width / 2.0; // Semi-major axis
    final b = depth / 2.0; // Semi-minor axis
    final centerX = a;
    final centerY = b;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < depth; y++) {
        final normalizedX = (x - centerX) / a;
        final normalizedY = (y - centerY) / b;
        if ((normalizedX * normalizedX) + (normalizedY * normalizedY) <= 1) {
          blocks[y][x] = true;
          blocks[depth - y - 1][x] = true; // Ensure vertical symmetry
          blocks[y][width - x - 1] = true; // Ensure horizontal symmetry
          blocks[depth - y - 1][width - x - 1] =
              true; // Ensure both horizontal and vertical symmetry
        }
      }
    }

    return blocks;
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [width, depth];
}
```

I thought of plotting on the screen in a GridView.

My question is, this code is plotting: (8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8) columns/rows (symmetric) but I wanted something way more "rounded" like (4, 6, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 6, 4).

Can anyone help me with the math for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The idea

What I would probably do, is use the forumula for the points on an ellipse:

```
x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse

Where `width = 2a` and `height = 2b`

Then, for each of the cells in your grid, you can calculate `x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2` see how much it diverts from 1, and use this to determine whether there should be a block in this position.

For example, say you have a 5x5 grid. The formula becomes

```
x^2/6.25 + y^2/6.25 = 1
```

### An example

For example, I quickly wrote up the following script (as inspiration, to play around with!)

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int width = 6;
  int height = 6;
  double treshold = 0.2;

  for (int x = (-width/2).round(); x <= (width/2).round(); x++) {
    String row = '';
    for (int y = (-height/2).round(); y <= (height/2).round(); y++) {
      double value = pow(x, 2)/pow(width/2, 2) + pow(y, 2)/pow(height/2, 2);
      row += '${(value - 1).abs() < treshold ? 'O' : ' '}';
    }
    print(row);
  }
}
```

Which, for the given parameters, outputs a pretty nice circle (if the characters where square):

```
  OOO  
 O   O 
O     O
O     O
O     O
 O   O 
  OOO
```

### Recommendation

You can play around with the parameters, the treshold for the values should probably depend on the width and height parameters. The circle is now centered around 0,0 which is why the for loops have become a bit messy, so you can also see if you can move the formula over.

Comment: Thanks for the main directions! It's really close to what I was looking for. It is not actually using the width and height that you set, it is using 7, but I think I can work around it. I'll leave this open for a couple of days so that other people can submit their suggestions as well for me to mark your suggestion as the accepted

Comment: Ah yeah, I see. I guess using round/ceil/floor should be able to resolve that, or testing in the mid-points of each 1x1 cell instead of the top left corner (i.e. (0.5,0.5) instead of (0,0))